# SVG masking not working with transform applied

Tags: css, svg, mask

I'm trying to apply mask to transformed svg element (it's simplified, I'm trying to do it with path, but structure is same). If mask is applied to element outside of transformed group, it works as expected. If I try to do the same inside , element just disappears.

HTML:

```
<svg width="350pt" height="100pt" >
  <defs>
    <pattern id="circleFill" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="5" height="5" > 
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" fill="red"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="circleMask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#circleFill)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(0,150) scale(.1,-.1)">
    <rect class="holder" x="300" y="300" height="1000" width="1000"/>
    <rect class="main t" x="350" y="350" height="400" width="400" />
  </g>
  <rect x="300" y="50" height="50" width="50" class="main masked o" />
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.holder {
    fill: darkgray;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.o{ fill: red; }
.t{ fill: purple; }
.masked{ mask: url(#circleMask); }
```

If I add "masked" class to second rect (with classes "main t"), it just disappears.

The following structure works:

```
<g class="masked">
  <g transform="...">
    <rect ... />
  </g>
</g>
```

I can't use it because I have more than 50 elements in image that should have the same transform and only some of them should be masked (and there are 5 different masks).

Here's the fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjfb69eo/)

What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to mask element inside transformed group?

Comment: You need to wrap the transformed group in another group and apply the mask to this one.

Comment: It's not a good way since mask should be applied to only a couple of ~50 elements in transformed group and it's applied dynamically with jQuery. Is there any other method?

Comment: If you add an explicit viewBox, this works fine.

Comment: @MichaelMullany, could you explain a bit more? Tried adding viewBox to <svg>, to <pattern> and to both of them - no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: If you add a viewBox that's sized to cover the original, pre-transformed content - the mask displays ok. https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/73050e81d2e36d25d340d070882e0c22?editors=1100 .

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks a lot, it works! Could you post it as answer so I can accept it?